# Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I couldn't understand why a query work as expected in PhpMyAdmin and from command line (mysql client) and not in PHP.

> Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE
>   '/var/www/html/domain.dom/tmp/qry_patients_11_11.csv' FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY " "
>   FROM qry_patients ; - Error: in
>   /var/www/html/domain.dom/export_csv.php on line 90

Line 90 and previous:

```
$where = "";
$tbl_name = "qry_patients"; // table name of the selected db
$FileName = "/var/www/html/domain.dom/tmp/".$tbl_name."_".date("h_i").".csv";
$query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".$FileName."' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" FROM ".$tbl_name." ".$where.";";
//$query = "SELECT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($linkDB, $query) OR trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

After 2 days I'm completely stucked. Please help me!
Ilic

Comment: Try double escaping the newline - `TERMINATED BY \"\\n\"`

Comment: Lines Terminated by doesn't contain newline in your error statement. Look at escaping newline character.

Comment: It does'nt work without TERMINATED BY too.


Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/domain.dom/tmp/qry_patients_02_22.csv' FROM qry_patients ;

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: GRANT FILE

THe problem was the user of MySQL. It does'nt have FILE permission in MySQL.

With GRANT FILE permission the query works as aspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRANT FILE

The problem was the user of MySQL. It does'nt have FILE permission in MySQL.

With GRANT FILE permission the query works as aspected.

My test from client and in PhpMyAdmin was performed with a full permission user.  :-)
The user I was triyng in PHP has grants only on one DB.

That's the reason the query does'nt work in my PHP script.